# Connecting a server to DSL router

Tags: linux, dsl

I have a broadband internet connection which is plugged in directly to my laptop. I have debian server with old configuration and currently connected to my laptop using bluetooth PAN connection. I want to purchase a DSL router as recommended by my ISP to access internet over wifi. I just wanted to know is it possible to connect my server to the router through LAN connection and gain access to it over wifi while sharing the internet connection at the same time? If so how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.

You don't need a DSL specific router, as any modern WiFi enabled router should do the trick. Most of these routers usually have 4+ ethernet ports for LAN connectivity plus the built in wireless.

You should be able to plug your server and laptop to the router via LAN, or connect them via Wifi, or any combination of both. If you plug your server into the LAN, you will be able to connect to it via your laptop connected through wifi without any further configuration. This is typically the default behavior of such devices.

This question really belongs over at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) though.

Comment: Not trying to spam, just to help. This D-Link router is on sale for $20, found at SlickDeals. Should do what you need. http://slickdeals.net/permadeal/93514/newegg-dlink-dir615-wireless-n300-router-wireless-n-usb-adapter-w-ddwrt-support